# render an unordered list as a <select> using CSS

Tags: html, css, select, html-lists

Is it possible to render an unordered list so that it appears to be a <\select> dropdown, by using CSS, but not using libraries such as jquery or mootools?
Thanks.
Neil.

Comment: Appears as, yes. Behaves as? No. Do you need the behaviour as well, or just the look?

Answer (score 0):

No. CSS is purely used for layout changes, and is incapable of adjusting HTML.

So you could make it *look* like one, but not *act* like one.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly style a UL to look and behave as a selectable list of elements.

However, the act of hiding/showing and selecting a value can only be achieved via javascript.